# Redirecting Wordpress users on login

Tags: wordpress, user-account, user, user-dashboard, user-interface

I'm just starting to work on CiviCRM for Wordpress, after having worked on CiviCRM for Drupal for such a long time. The one thing I dislike about wordpress is that when a user goes to log in, they are directed to the admin portal.

So I was wondering what others did to just direct members only to their profile page on the website, rather than to the admin portal after loggin in.

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [Peter's Login Redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/) successfully for a similar purpose.

Comment: I also use this plugin you can redirect based on role, user and other options. You can also customize logout redirects. Very handy.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the `login_redirect` filter. You can return whatever URL you like for whoever's logging in:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

Answer (score 3):

I use a WP Redirect After Login Plugin. It is in the WP Plugin Library. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/ 
I just change the Subscriber Role (or whatever Role your Members are defaulted to) to go to the dashboard url.

I have not had any conflicts with my theme or Civi with this Plugin.  As of 10/19/2016