# Create a Login page for wordpress users to access civicrm but not wordpress functionality

Tags: wordpress

We have installed CiviCRM on Wordpress and I'd like to create a login page for all users of the CRM.

I've created all employees as users in Wordpress and contacts in CiviCRM.

How do I create a login page so they are immediately taken to CiviCRM and cannot see or access the Wordpress backend? Right now they all logging to Wordpress (not CIviCRM) and have to click the CiviCRM module in the left Wordpress menu.

In the demos on Drupal users cannot see the backend.

This topic is not covered int he documentation that I can see.

Comment: See this post, it has a few options: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15405/redirecting-wordpress-users-on-login

Answer (score 1):

There are many plugins that do front-end login forms.  I have been using [Login with Ajax](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-with-ajax/)  This will create a front end form and allow redirects.   You can also leverage the login widget in the [Members Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) and pair that with [Peter's Login redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/peters-login-redirect/)

Comment: I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirect-after-login/

Comment: I've used 'Theme my Login' to give a pretty front end and redirect users to a certain page (per role).

Answer (score 0):

Given that all login would have to be done through Wordpress as CivicRM does not hold any of the login information it self (e.g. password). I would advise you to look for or build a wordpress plugin that does this for you.

Regards

Seamus

Answer (score 0):

You also can https://www.role-editor.com/ plugin to give you a more detailed control of what your users have access to when they login. This along with the CiviCRM ACL manager, should also get you the results you want. They will still login to the WP dashboard and need to click on CiviCRM on the left. But you can limit how much they can see of the WP dashboard.